# Unresponsive MAUI Android app, no user interaction possible

Tags: maui, maui-android

I have some rare cases where users of my app complain that the entire app becomes unresponsive and that no further interaction is possible with all controls and buttons (Clicked event handlers and Tapped GestureRecognizers).
However, according to a screen video from a user no ANR or crash is occurring. It seems like all event handlers and commands are disconnected.

On the pages of occurrence no background tasks or other tasks are running in the app (happens on the login page as well as the main app screen after login).
On the login screen it seems the issue occurs after showing the keyboard to enter the password.

MAUI 7.0.92, .NET 7.0.9, .NET SDK 7.0.306
occurs on MAUI Android only

Affected users can reproduce the issue each time when running the app.

Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce this on all of my test devices. The issue occurred on earlier MAUI versions too.

Any thoughts on how to tackle down this issue?

Comment: Even if you cannot reproduce the issue, can you at least narrow it down? Where in your code do you suspect the issue? With the current information, it's near impossible to help you properly, I think. Maybe you can show some of the code of the places where the issue appears to occur? Could be a problem related to async-await, MainThread, some deadlock...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is a bug in the Mopups library I used for displaying popups when accessibility features on Samsung Android devices are enabled.

https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups/issues/77

Comment: Ahhh the beauty of 3rd party xamarin libs. Almost working, almost everywhere. (Yes, xamarin)

Comment: @H.A.H. After investigating Mopups library it turned out there is a bug in MAUI causing this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16476